# Best frameworks to make slides in HTML5

Tags: html

I want to do a presentation using HTML5. If some of you already use a good HTML5 framework to make slides please can you give me the links.
I like this one :
http://slides.html5rocks.com

But I want to have more information before choosing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/)
- [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/)
- [html5slides](http://code.google.com/p/html5slides/)

I personally prefer reveal.js. Simple enough to easily create slides, but still powerful enough to do everything I want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have used and been impressed by impress.js:

http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js

Its output is very similar to Prezi.

Answer (score 1):

[Bunkr](https://www.bunkr.me/) is super convenient and fun to use, and nice enough.
But I haven't found a slide show framework that can handle math. 
Hopefully they'll add this feature soon!

Update: reveal.js can use MathJax to handle math, as described [here](https://www.bunkr.me/).